# How to 'warm up' LED output color without changing the bulbs

Tags: recessed-lighting

I tried to ask this question before, but I don't think I was clear. I replaced my recessed lighting with recessed dimmable LED fixtures.  The bulbs are contained in the fixture, and I don't believe they can be changed. Perhaps I'm wrong about that. They are from Commercial Electric, Model T61.  They are 6" recessed LED swivel fixtures and I really don't think there's any way to change the bulbs inside. If I'm wrong and you know a way to change them, I'd so appreciate it.  They are labeled "soft white", but they are bright and harsh.  They are dimmable, but even at the lowest setting they are pretty bright. So are there photo gels or some other way to "warm up" the lighting to more closely match my old halogens which were just beautiful.

Comment: You may be able to add a polarizing film that will both reduce the light and dampen the "harshness". This can work with led because they don't generate the heat that halogens do. Just an idea to try.

Comment: You return the whole fixture, and get different fixtures, in that case.

Comment: @EdBeal rather than a polarizing filter, why not use a warm-up filter (many examples, here's one: http://www.leefilters.com/lighting/colour-details.html#205&filter=cf for photographic lighting).  To the OP -- yes there are warm-up gels.

Comment: Chris those would also work +

Answer (score 0):

If you look at, e.g., [this Amazon page](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B3XYVWQ) and scroll down to "similar units," you'll see a variety of similar fixtures which are color-temperature rated. (The lower the temperature, the redder the output color balance).  I rather doubt you can easily swap out the LED in the fixture you bought, and it's certainly not worth the money you (probably won't) save.